# NodeJS like interrupt handlers?

Tags: node.js, ms-dos

I got started with programming back in the DOS days. One of my early projects involved overriding the keyboard interrupt service routine with my own. Now I'm trying out NodeJS to update myself, and I feel there is a similarity between the non-blocking design of NodeJS and my old experience with interrupt service routines (ISR). My guess is the similarity would be the keyboard ISR would wait for a key press input signal from the keyboard, while NodeJS waits for a web request. When the input arrives, both NodeJS and the ISR need to hurry to handle the request and say they're done in case a new input arrives. That is, there is a penalty for a CPU bound task slowing down the next web response or the next keyboard key input. Is this observation a reasonable understanding?  I'm new to NodeJS so perhaps I'm missing an important difference or just incorrect in some fundamental way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of.

Interrupt Service Routines are really just hardware hooks so that the keyboard or other hardware device can make a subroutine call to the operating system while maintaining a degree of isolation.  There's a lot more to it, of course, and if the method appears to be asynchronous, it's only because operating systems back then were capable of rudimentary *task switching,* or maybe even *cooperative multitasking.*

Node.JS's mechanism of operation is a bit different.  Node.JS has an event loop that receives requests, each of which it assigns to a new thread under the covers.  An async handler is registered to receive the eventual result of the requests.  Everything happens at a much higher level of abstraction.

Comment: How are Node.JS apps different (or claimably efficient) from Tomcat applications as both of them use an underlying thread pool to process requests?

Answer (score -1):

There are Interrupt Service Routines and Sub-routines which are different implementation of control flow. Usually the CPU runs everything in the main function often called a *routine*. In this function all the repetitive tasks happen including I/O polling. When you hit a key on your keyboard the function that was running at the time which is the "routine" is pushed to the stack to save progress and immediately a service to handle the command from the keyboard is invoked from the register(memory address) where it is saved. When the cpu finishes executing that service it pops off the former routine off the stack and resumes. This behavior of certain crucial events interrupting the normal routine of the CPU is `Interrupting`. The suite of services that encapsulate logic for responding to these interrupts is called `Interrupt Service Routine` and its just a location in the memory where all services are stored. You can read more about the CPU. When the CPU is not interrupted, it is polling i.e routine checks for I/O ports to check wether there are any queueing tasks to run. Polling alone is not enough so to serve crucial events e.g shutdown on battery low the CPU uses a `priority ladder` which ranks events according to priority. This is the basis of ISR. This enables the computer to shutdown even when performing an important task. When a high priority event flag is raised, the lower priority routine is pushed to the stack and resumes after the execution of the latter. NodeJS on the other hand implements polling through the event loop with the exception of `process.nexttick()` and `process.microtask`. These are the only subroutines that run outside the polling framework. They are not interrupts since event loop does not abandon currently running phase of the event loop. Event loop simply waits for the current phase to finish and immediately jumps to the `nexttick` or `microtask` incase their queues have pending tasks. If no tasks are pending event loop will move to the next phase of the event loop until the cycle is over then begin a new one if there are any tasks otherwise exit the process.